# After Completion of Animation want to call some methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, animation

In my iPhone application

I am doing certain animations.
 like

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"stalk" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    self.frame=originalSelf;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

After completion of this animation I want tocall some methods...

I know something abt block animations or

DidStopAnimation notification

How do I do that....
Thanks..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On iOS 4 and later, using blocks is recommended for this purpose:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 
                     animations:^{
                         self.frame=originalSelf;} 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){

                        //My method call;
                     }
     ];
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"stalk" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(afterAnimationStops)]
self.frame=originalSelf;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

And then you can implement method

```
-(void)afterAnimationStops{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
animateWithDuration:animations:completion:
```

Here's some more information: http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html

Here's an example:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{self.frame=originalSelf;} completion:^(BOOL finished){/*have your completion code here*/}];
```